# R: after identify a "1", repeat (carry foward) "1" until the end of the records of the ID

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a tibble with "id" and "rec":

```
a <- tibble(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
            rec = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0))
a
```

I need to create another column (here called "result"), and so the value of the column "result" will be equal to the "rec" or, after finding a "1" in the "rec" column, "1" for all of the following rows until the end of the vector of that "id", like that:

```
b <- tibble(a, result = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1))
b
```

Is there some way to do this using tidyverse way?, something like:

```
a %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(result = ...) %>% ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2):

`cummax` may be needed after grouping by 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
a <- a %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(result = cummax(rec)) %>%
    ungroup
```